# Angular Nativescript mono repo with non-Nativescript projects

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am working in a team that is using a monolithic repository for web-based Angular projects. This is using the Angular CLI projects (libs/applications) setup.

For one of our web projects, we want to add NativeScript mobile applications. The intention is reusing a few of our libs (model/validation logic) for the mobile applications.

Is it possible to 'ng generate *Nativescript Application* etc', so that it exists within our current monolithic project structure?

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Yes, you may migrate existing Angular app to {N} code sharing with [nativescript-schematics](https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript-schematics#migrating-web-components-to-a-shared-components).

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I'm trying to do the same.